# Can't serve a site using homestead

Tags: laravel, homestead

Recently I can't run Laravel homestead up and it says that my VM has become 'inaccessible' - Vagrant no longer working. So, I reinstalled everything but when I tried to serve a site locally, it gives me this message.

`dos2unix: /vagrant/scripts/serve-laravel.sh: No such file or directory
dos2unix: Skipping /vagrant/scripts/serve-laravel.sh, not a regular file.
bash: /vagrant/scripts/serve-laravel.sh: No such file or directory`

When I go to the url it gives me: `No input file specified.`

I think I miss something.

Answer (score 2):

You have an updated vagrant install with older homestead setup. Where homestead is looking for

```
/vagrant/scripts/serve-laravel.sh
```

file which should be now kept as

```
/vagrant/scripts/serve.sh
```

You can either rename above file by using

```
vagrant ssh
cp /vagrant/scripts/serve.sh /vagrant/scripts/serve-laravel.sh
```

Or update your homestead as well.
After that serving your file as

```
serve yourapp.dev /code/yourapp/public/
```

Hope this helps
P.S. : the command is not needed using the new version of homestead

Comment: Thanks for this. I just recently fixed the error when I restarted everything. Kind of weird but when I came back and run `homestead up` , `homestead ssh` and served the sand voila it works.